# Does a valid email have to be used for Firebase authentication?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebase Realtime Database for my university project, to store data from my Unity game. However, due to ethics concerns, I cannot ask users for an email/password so they can register and then sign up. So my idea was to generate a random email/password combo for the user, but I am not sure if the emails used in the functions `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` and `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` have to be real emails or if I can just make them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the email used in the `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync()` and
> `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync()` methods have to be a real email?

The answer is **no**, you can use a fake email. However note that the user will not be able to use the forget password function.